# How to use aws cli in python or node.js programming language?

Tags: python, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-cli

1. How do i use awscli command in python or node.js programming?
2. My final aim is to attach security group to running instances in AWS.

   ```
   aws --region us-east-1 ec2 modify-instance-attribute --instance-id i-782cc9fb --groups sg-47fb243f
   ```

I want to run this command through python programming code or nodejs . is there any way to do?

Comment: There is a very popular library to achieve what you want in python called Boto: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/boto

Comment: Use the AWS SDKs for Python (also known as Boto3) and NodeJS instead of calling the CLI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very easy to do using Boto2 libraries. Make sure your credentials are set correctly in `~/.aws/credentials` or pass them in `boto.connect_ec2()`. Much simpler in Boto3. Following is using Boto2.

```
import boto

conn = boto.connect_ec2()
reservations = conn.get_all_instances(instance_ids=['i-782cc9fb'])
instance = reservations[0].instances[0]
instance.modify_attribute('groupSet', ['sg-47fb243f'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Why shell out to the command line, from within python? The AWS command line is just a front end to the python boto library. You can do it directly.

Boto: http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/

Anyway... Subprocess module, something like the following:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["aws", "--region", "us-east-1", "ec2", "modify-instance-attribute", "--instance-id", "i-782cc9fb", "--groups", "sg-47fb243f"])
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html